# visualise difference between two geom_hex plots by subtracting data

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to visualise the difference between two `geom_hex` plots with a new, third hexagon plot?

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) +
  geom_hex(aes(fill = stat(ncount)))
```

[image]

```
set.seed(123)
diamonds2 <- diamonds %>%
  mutate(price = jitter(price, amount = 500), carat = jitter(carat, amount = 2))

ggplot(diamonds2, aes(carat, price)) +
  geom_hex(aes(fill = stat(ncount)))
```

[image]

I've thought of extracting the data using `ggplot_build`, manipulating them and reassembling the plot, but that leads to problems with the fact that the bins aren't the same and that I'd need to somehow adjust the colour scale.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to play with `alpha` and `col`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
diamonds2 <- diamonds %>%
  mutate(price = jitter(price, amount = 500), carat = jitter(carat, amount = 2))


ggplot() +
  geom_hex(data = diamonds, aes(carat, price, col = "red", alpha = 0.3, fill = stat(ncount))) +
  geom_hex(data = diamonds2, aes(carat, price, col = "blue", alpha = 0.3, fill = stat(ncount)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Yes, I could do this, thanks. However I was actually hoping to create a third plot that shows the difference